# Change searched term

Tags: query, search, pre-get-posts

So I'm trying to set up a search form in which which the term actually searched for would be different than what the user entered in. Specifically, I needed any dashes in the searched terms removed. For example, let's say the user enters "7-18". What the search actually needs to query is "718". I'm thinking

```
pre_get_posts
```

might be the way to go but I'm not sure how to go about writing it. Something like

```
function alter_query($query) {
$unedit = the_search_query();
$edited = str_replace("-","",$unedit);
the_search_query() = $edited;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');
```

Takes the entered value, removes the dashes, and uses it at the new search query in the search form. It doesn't work though, and I don't know if it's because you can't set the_search_query() with php, because it forms a loop, or if there is some other reason. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The `pre_get_posts` filter is the right place to go. You can check if you are on a search query, and alter it the way you want. Here's an example:

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    // Check if we are on a search page
    if ($query->is_search) {

      // Get the search query
      $search_term = get_search_query();

      // You can modify the search query here, and pass it to the query again.
      $search_term = str_replace( "-", "" , $search_term );

      $query->set( 's', $search_term  );

    }

  }

}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```